# instagrapi- 'Location' not defined

Tags: python, instagrapi

I'm trying to automate some Instagram posts with instagrapi, which is the only tool I've found that supports album uploads. The documentation officially has the following example:

```
>>> media = cl.photo_upload(
    "/app/image.jpg",
    "Test caption for photo with #hashtags and mention users such @example",
    usertags=[Usertag(user=example, x=0.5, y=0.5)],
    location=Location(name='Russia, Saint-Petersburg', lat=59.96, lng=30.29)
```

However, I get an error with the following code:

```
    bot.album_upload(paths='temp/',
                     caption=text,
                     location=Location(name='Amsterdam, Netherlands'))
```

The error is:

```
NameError: name 'Location' is not defined
```

I've tried just doing

```
    bot.album_upload(paths=album,
                     caption=text,
                     location='Amsterdam, Netherlands')
```

but then I get

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'external_id'
```

What am I doing incorrectly? TIA, I'm very new to this library.

Comment: Did you import it? per the documentation `from instagrapi.types import Usertag, Location`

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much. I can't believe I overlooked this.